# iOS Universal link not working

Tags: ios, ios9

My server is returning the content that's supposed to be in the route `apple-app-site-association` with the correct teamID + bundleID and with the path `/app/myresource/34`

I enabled the `Associated Domains` and added both my staging and production server's domain like this: `applinks:production.com`, `applinks:project.staging.com`

When I go to `http://project.staging.com/app/myresource/34` on simulator's Safari, it doesn't deep link. Did I miss something?

PS: the JSON contained in `http://project.staging.com/apple-app-site-association` is not SSL signed, but I read since iOS 9 beta 2 you don't need to sign, also I have security transport allowing `HTTP` connections and I'm successfully able to retrieve data from my staging server with no SSL.

PS2: this is my json, just in case:

```
{
   "applinks": {
       "apps": [ ],
       "details": {
           "my-team-id.my.bundle.Id": {
               "paths": [
                   "/app/myresource/*"
               ]
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be the format of JSON:

```
 {
   "applinks": {
       "apps": [ ],
       "details": [
           {
               "appID": "T5TQ36Q2SQ.com.branch.sdk.TestBed",
               "paths": [ "*" ]
           }
       ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server **must** be using HTTPS but your example is not.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

> Adding support for universal links is easy. There are three steps you
>   need to take:
>
> - Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle.
> - Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your **HTTPS web server**.
> - Prepare your app to handle universal links.

Answer (score 1):

As in Apple Doc stated:

> Always use actual devices to test universal links. Simulator doesn’t
>   support universal links.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW2